# Everytime I refresh page items duplicates in local storage

Tags: javascript, google-maps, local-storage, google-maps-markers

I know that code is a mess I found it somewhere. And I see that a lot of functions are called multiple times and I don't know how to fix that. I never worked with localStorage but I need this time. When I refresh the page items duplicate in localStorage and it makes the site buggy literally unusable. If anyone knows how to optimize this I would appreciate it.

```js
var map,
    markersAll = [];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044}
  });

  renderMarkers();

  map.addListener('click', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latLng.lat();
    var lng = e.latLng.lng();    
    generateMarker(lat, lng);    
    //console.log(lat, lng);
  });  
}

let markers = getMarkersFromLocalStorage()
console.log(markers)
function getMarkersFromLocalStorage(){
  return localStorage.markers ? JSON.parse(localStorage.markers) : []
}

function addMarkerToLocalStorage(lat, lng) {
  markers.push({lat, lng});
  localStorage.markers = JSON.stringify(markers);
};

function removeMarkerFromLocalStorage(lat, lng) {
  let newMarkers = [];
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    if(marker.lat != lat && marker.lng != lng) {
      newMarkers.push({
        lat: marker.lat,
        lng: marker.lng
      });
    }
  });

  localStorage.markers = JSON.stringify(newMarkers);
};

function clearMarkers() {
  markersAll.forEach((marker) => {
    marker.setMap(null);
  });
};

function renderMarkers() {
  markers.forEach(function(marker) {
    console.log(marker.lat, marker.lng);
    generateMarker(marker.lat, marker.lng);
  });
};

var marker
var icon = {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
  strokeColor: "blue",
  scale: 3
}

function generateMarker(lat, lng) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
    map: map,
    icon: icon
  }); 
    marker.setMap(map);
    markersAll.push(marker);
    addMarkerToLocalStorage(lat, lng);
    // changing icon on click

  marker.addListener('rightclick', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latLng.lat();
    var lng = e.latLng.lng();
    //console.log('right click', lat, lng);
    clearMarkers();
    removeMarkerFromLocalStorage(lat, lng);
    // renderMarkers();    
  });   
  
  marker.addListener('click', changeColor);

};

function changeColor(evt) {
  this.setIcon(pinSymbol('blue'));
}

function pinSymbol(color) {
    return {
        path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
        fillColor: color,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        strokeColor: '#000',
        strokeWeight: 2,
        scale: 1
    };
}
// clear all markers
document.getElementById('clear-all-markers').addEventListener('click', clearAllMarkers)
function clearAllMarkers(){
  localStorage.clear()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time your page runs it will create markers and add them to local storage.

```
function addMarkerToLocalStorage(lat, lng) {
  markers.push({lat, lng});
  localStorage.markers = JSON.stringify(markers);
};
```

The function above does this. But this function does not have any logic to check if a marker exist, and without knowing what the use case is, I am not sure it is meant to.

The code has a function to clear all markers

```
// clear all markers
document.getElementById('clear-all-markers').addEventListener('click', clearAllMarkers)

function clearAllMarkers(){
  localStorage.clear()
}
```

But this is attached to a button "clear-all-markers" shown above.

You could force the code to automatically clear the markers by calling the clearAllMarkers(); function at the very top of the code; like this:

```
var map,
    markersAll = [];
clearAllMarkers(); // this will clear local storage
```

Another option is to change the addMarkerToLocalStorage code so that it checks if the marker exists, this will prevent many markers from existing from one location - again this might not be your desired usecase

```
function addMarkerToLocalStorage(lat, lng) {
  var add = true;
  // check if this marker exists!
  markers.forEach(function(marker){
    if (marker.lat===lat && marker.lng===lng) add=false;
  })
  // did we find the marker? exit
  if (add===false) return;
  markers.push({lat, lng});
  localStorage.markers = JSON.stringify(markers);
};
```

I would guess option two might be what you need, but from the information you provided I have no idea what the use case of this code is.

Comment: I just wanted to click somewhere and save that to localStorage when I come back to make it at the same location. and on Rightclick to delete it also to change color when I click on it

Comment: If you check I have updated my answer so it will not add the same marker over and over. Try using the new code for addMarkerToLocalStorage ... This code is not tested but should do the trick

Comment: It works now with if statement thank you!

Comment: This is working on the basis that it does not keep adding the same markers as you reload. It sounds like you need a more complex code solution. But I this this answers your issue for now.

Comment: One more question If you don't mind. When I right-click to delete them I delete them successfully but all markers disappear so I need to refresh to see what's left.

Comment: Edit the function marker.addListener('rightclick', function(e) {
    var lat = e.latLng.lat();
    var lng = e.latLng.lng();
    //console.log('right click', lat, lng);
    clearMarkers();
    removeMarkerFromLocalStorage(lat, lng);
    renderMarkers();    
  });

Comment: Un-comment the line renderMarkers();

Comment: I tried but problem is that every time I click right-click it makes a new position in local storage. But when i refresh its deleted from storage and disappear from the map